# Using R expss and data.table is it possible to load data.table labels from a csv file instead of typing the code in by hand?

Tags: r, data.table, label, expss

Applying labels is an important part of making survey data comprehensible when reported

So the best example I can find uses expss::apply_labels()
e.g the famous mtcars example https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/vignettes/tables-with-labels.html

as input this requires a data.table and a list of comma separated assignment pairs e.g

```
apply_labels(dt, col1 = "label1", col2 = "label2", col3 = "label3")
```

This is fine if you have one data file and a few columns and you can be bothered typing them in for each time, but its not very helpful if you have lots of data files. So how could one load a csv metadata file
in format:

**Col1    Col2    Col3**

Label1  Label2  Label3

where the Col names match the same names in the data table

this means effectively translating the metadata csv file so that it generates

col*n* = "label*n*"

for each column.

So far I have found the biggest problem is that the apply labels column names are objects not strings and it is very difficult to translate a string to the object in the right scope.

This is where I've got to

```
    library(expss)
    library(data.table)
    library(glue)

    readcsvdata <- function(dfile)
     {
        rdata <- fread(file = dfile, sep = "," , quote = "\"" , header = TRUE, 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = getOption("datatable.na.strings","NA"))
        return(rdata)
        }

    rawdatafilename <- "testdata.csv"
    rawmetadata <- "metadata.csv"

    mdt <- readcsvdata(rawmetadata)
    rdt <-readcsvdata(rawdatafilename)
    commonnames <- intersect(names(mdt),names(rdt))  # find common 
    qlabels <- as.character(mdt[1, commonnames, with = FALSE])

    comslist <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(commonnames)) # loop through commonnames and qlabels
          {  
          if (i == length(commonnames))
              {x <- glue('{commonnames[i]} = "{qlabels[i]}"')} # no comma for final item
              else 
              {x <- glue('{commonnames[i]} = "{qlabels[i]}",')} # comma for next item

          comslist[[i]] <- x
    }

comstring <- paste(unlist(comslist), collapse = '')

tdt = apply_labels(tdt, eval(parse(text = comstring)))
```

which yields

Error in parse(text = comstring) : :1:24: unexpected ',' 1: varone = "Label1", ^

oh and print(comstring) produces:

> [1] "varone = \"Question one\",vartwo = \"Question two\",varthree =
>   \"Question three\",varfour = \"Question four\",varfive = \"Question
>   five\",varsix = \"Question six\",varseven = \"Question
>   seven\",vareight = \"Question eight\",varnine = \"Question
>   nine\",varten = \"Question ten\""

Comment: If that's truly a CSV file, and you read that in with `read.csv` (or `fread` or whatever), then `do.call(apply_labels, c(list(dt), csvdat))` should work.

Comment: You can use `var_lab` in a loop: `for(each in colnames(metadata)) var_lab(dt[[each]]) = metadata[[each]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_labels` is not very convenient for assignment labels from external dictionary. You can use `var_lab` instead:

```
library(expss)
library(data.table)

readcsvdata <- function(dfile)
{
    rdata <- fread(file = dfile, sep = "," , quote = "\"" , header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = getOption("datatable.na.strings","NA"))
    return(rdata)
}

rawdatafilename <- "testdata.csv"
rawmetadata <- "metadata.csv"

mdt <- readcsvdata(rawmetadata)
rdt <-readcsvdata(rawdatafilename)
commonnames <- intersect(names(mdt),names(rdt))  # find common 
qlabels <- as.list(mdt[1, commonnames, with = FALSE])


for (each_name in commonnames) # loop through commonnames and qlabels
{  
    var_lab(rdt[[each_name]]) <- qlabels[[each_name]]
}
```

There is a similar `val_lab` function for value labels. Additionally you may be interested in `apply_dictionary` and `create_dictionary` functions. To get help about them type `?apply_dictionary` in the console.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Small point however
var_lab(rdt[[each_name]]) = qlabels[[each_name]]    doesn't work
var_lab(rdt[[each_name]]) <- qlabels[[each_name]]   (as per manual) does.
if you would like to edit. Cheers.

Comment: @PeterKing Thanks for reporting. I edited the answer. But really it is very strange - it should have no difference  in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `expss` handy, but I think this is generically about how to programmatically assign function arguments in R.

If you start with a CSV file that contains the three pairings you need,

```r
csvdat <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
col1,col2,col3
label1,label2,label3")
```

I'll write a fake function (since I don't have `expss`, and it's not critical) that takes a first argument and zero or more follow-on arguments dynamically.

```r
my_fake_labels <- function(x, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  message("x labels   : ", paste(sQuote(colnames(x)), collapse = ", "))
  message("other names: ", paste(sQuote(names(dots)), collapse = ", "))
}
origDT <- data.table(aa=1, bb=2)

my_fake_labels(origDT, col1="label1", col2="label2", col3="label3")
# x labels   : 'aa', 'bb'
# other names: 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
```

It's that manual argument-setting that you're trying to avoid. (I know I'm not doing any label-setting here, let's ignore that for now.)

The programmatic way of doing this, using `origDT` as the first argument, and the elements of `csvdat` as the second and subsequent arguments:

```r
do.call(my_fake_labels, c(list(origDT), csvdat))
# x labels   : 'aa', 'bb'
# other names: 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
```

The second argument to `do.call` needs to be a `list`, optionally named. Since a `data.frame` (and therefore a `data.table`) is just a glorified named `list`, this fits the bill. What this does is take each element of the list and apply it as the corresponding arguments of the function (the first argument of `do.call`).

The `list(origDT)` is because normally the `c(...)` function would concatenate the columns/elements of the two lists. If we did just `c(origDT, csvdat)`, then the function would be called with `ncol(origDT) + ncol(csvdat)` arguments, instead of the desired `1 + ncol(csvdat)`. For this, `c(list(origDT), ...)` makes sure that the whole `origDT` is the function's first argument.

(It might also be easy to form the `csvdat` programmatically instead of requiring an external file, but I'm guessing that you have a reason to do it via CSV.)

Comment: This may be very sophisticated but I'm afraid I simply don't understand it. I don't see what your function my_fake_labels is for. Is it a proxy for expss apply_labels for the sake of argument? What is list(...)?  Please forgive a struggling beginner.

Comment: *"I'll write a fake function (since I don't have expss)"*. Add to that *"this fake function takes the same arguments as your `apply_labels` so behaves similarly as far as we need it to here"*. Just replace it with your `expss::apply_labels` and see what happens.

Comment: `list(...)` is R's way of (re)packaging up an arbitrary (0 or more) length of arguments.

Comment: Tried do.call adding the first parameter (name of the datatable) 
tdt <- copy(rdt)
comslist <- prepend(comslist,"tdt")  # using purrr
tdt <- do.call(expss::apply_labels,comslist)
result was
Error in UseMethod("apply_labels") : no applicable method for 'apply_labels' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: I think that `purrr::prepend` is stripping the class from your `comslist`, so `expss::apply_labels` does not know what to do with it. I don't know why you are pre-pending a literal string `"tdt"` to the list, though, that seems odd. Can't you just do `do.call(apply_labels, c(tdt, comslist))`?